# Maximize area of triangle

Tags: derivatives, optimization, triangles

I'm trying to maximize the area of a triangle with the following three sides.
The first side is the **y=0**, the second lies on the line **y = 3x**, and the third passes through the **point (1,1)**.

I want to find the slope of the third line that maximizes the area of the triangle. I used the equation **A = ($ \frac{1}{2} b\cdot h $)** and solving for the height in terms of the base.

I then combined those equations to get an equation for the area. When I maximize this and test my answers they don't seem to be working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Your strategy seems sound, but we can't find your mistake if you don't show your work.

Comment: As per Matthew: Please show your workings; perhaps we can help find if there are any calculation errors.

Comment: You want to maximize the area of the triangle.  Hence, you want to find base, height in terms of one variable, to sub *into the Area formula*, to find the derivative of area wrt the common variable.

Comment: Note that the side through $A=(1,1)$ and the altitude through the origin $O$ to this side meet at right-angles at a point $P$. $P$ therefore lies on the circle with diameter $OA$. In case this makes life easier. Always draw a diagram for this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm gonna explain some of my work. I calculated the equation of the third line to be h = (1/(1-b))((h/3)-b). Solving for h I got h = -3b/(-3b+2). I then plugged this into the area formula to get A = -3b^2/(2(-3b+2)). When I took the derivative I got (3b(3b-4))/(2(3x-2)^2). Finding the zeros I got b = 4/3. When I test this answer I find other numbers for b which give higher areas of the triangles.

Comment: That's good, but please just edit the question to include that work.

Comment: You seem to be talking about vertices rather than sides. If so, my mental picture of the triangle is one in which the area increases endlessly with the value of $x$. Just draw the picture and you may get some ideas, possibly the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can make triangles with the given conditions and the area as large as you wish.

Thus there is no maximum area for such triangles.

---

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the two equations $$y=3x$$ and $$y=m(x-1)+1$$to compute the third point of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum, however there is a minimum area.

Consider the third side having slope $-\varepsilon$ where $0<\varepsilon\ll 1$ (so almost parallel to the $x$-axis).  Then it has base $1+\varepsilon^{-1}$ (the vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1+\varepsilon^{-1},0)$ on the $x$-axis) and height $\approx 1$, so having area approximately proportional to $\varepsilon^{-1}\to\infty$ as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.

Indeed the graph of the area as a function of the inverse-slope of side through (1,1) (constraint $\mu=m^{-1}<\frac13$) is a branch of an oblique hyperbola, so giving a minimum (at $\mu=-\frac13$ as your $b=\frac43$ indicates).

Answer (score 0):

You have two sides given of your triangle, the lines, $y=0$ and $y=3x$.

Use the point-slope form of a line to express the line passing through $(1,1)$: $\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=m$, where $y_0=1$ and $x_o$=1. In this case $m$ is the slope we want to find.

We want to find where the line through $(1,1)$ intersects the other line boundaries, so you need to solve $3x=m(x-1)+1$ and $0=m(x-1)+1$. Solve for $x$ and $y$. Take the $y$ for where the line through $(1,1)$ intersects as your height and the $x$ coordinate where the line through $(1,1)$ intersects the x-axis as your base. Insert into the Area formula you mention above.

You should end up solving a quadratic equation in $m$.